# windows 7 not resolving a specific host

Tags: windows, dns, ubuntu-12.04, samba

In my home network I have a desktop (ubuntu 12.04 - as a server), laptop (Windows 7 Ultimate x86 for work) and android phone. Since I installed samba3.6.3 with apt-get and configured shares only

I can't resolve correctly the server from my laptop using a domain I bought and configured, no matter the network it's in. I tried the office, some internet cafes and pub networks - it always fails to connect to any service. The problem is only with the laptop. Other computers from any network resolve it correctly and get service they require (ftp, ssh, httpd).

I tried flushing dns cache with `ipconfig /flushdns` and it emptied the output `ipconfig /displaydns` with no success.

Tracert does only one hop. Tracing the domain I bought leads directly to the public IP of the server and tracing the local domain leads to the local ip address of the server.

I have zero ideas how this happened. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does your samba server use the same domain name? Your windows computer might be resolving the name via WINS and not via DNS at all...

Comment: No, the server has a different local name. Good guess tho. I'm considering reinstall windows and leave it for some linux distro...